# How to update values by column name from subselect?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need for a given `USER_ID` (for example `999`) to find all `CAR_ID` that the given `USER_ID` does not yet have, but other `USER_ID` do.

My assumptions:

1. In the subquery `SELECT`, find all `CAR_ID` for all other `USER_IDs` without duplicates
2. Now you need to replace all found `USER_ID` with my only `USER_ID` (for example `999`) and `INSERT` these values.

But I can't replace all `CAR_ID` that I get as a result of executing the `SELECT` subquery:

Maybe something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO task(instance_id, user_id, car_id) (SELECT DISTINCT instance_id, 999, car_id
                                                FROM task
                                                WHERE user_id <> 999);
```

[image]

Comment: What about the column `instance_id`? Does this have anything to do with your requirement?

Comment: @forpas, No, not related with requirement

Comment: But you use it in the INSERT statement which means that it should have a non-null value, right?

Comment: @forpas, right, but in this task - doesn't matter, you can use `NULL`

Comment: Your `SELECT` is not doing what you think: 1) The `DISTINCT` includes `instance_id` which means it will return duplicates for a `user_id`, `car_id` e.g. 'ILC, 2, 2' and 'ABCX,2,2'.  2) `user_id <> 999`  means you are just ignoring that `user_id` not checking whether that `user_id`  has `car_id`'s in common with other users.

Comment: I was not correct on my 1) point because I thought `user_id` had been  included in the `DISTINCT`. I'm blaming it on lack of coffee  2) Still remains an issue as `user_id` of 999 has a `car_id` of 1. The `DISTINCT`  will find a `car_id` of 1 for the other `instance_id`'s.  That means you will be inserting it a 'new' `car_id` of 1 for user 999 when it is not. Actually you will be inserting multiple `car_id`'s of 1 as both the 'ILC' and 'ABC' `instance_id`'s have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this query will help you I've not tested it yet but you can replace your sub-query with the following, this query will return all the unique car-ids that user 999 doesn't have.

```
Select Distinct null as instance_id,999 as user_id,car_id From task
where user_id!=999 and car_id not in 
(Select Distinct car_id From task where user_id=999)
```

So after this, your whole query looks like this

```
INSERT INTO task(instance_id, user_id, car_id) Select Distinct null as 
instance_id,999 as user_id,car_id From task where user_id!=999 and car_id 
not in (Select Distinct car_id From task where user_id=999)
```

So let me know if this will work for you or not

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
INSERT INTO task(user_id, car_id)
SELECT 999, car_id
FROM task
GROUP BY car_id
HAVING SUM((user_id = 999)::int) = 0;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=577a08b53b6c07da007dc06fddcac705).

or, with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO task(user_id, car_id)
SELECT DISTINCT 999, t1.car_id
FROM task t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM task t2 WHERE t2.user_id = 999 AND t2.car_id = t1.car_id);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b8f21e47de48a3a5b4e02d5532dac414).